# ERROR NameError: global name 'v1' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I'm trying to create a kind of calculator. I tested the code that I made on a new file, and it works. But now, when I put the code on my program file this error appears.

```
v1 = v1.get()
NameError: global name 'v1' is not defined
```

And here is my code:

```
def calc_price():

    cp = Tk()
    cp.title("Calcular Preço")

    def plus():
        global v1
        global v2
        global r
        v1 = v1.get()
        v2 = v2.get()
        v1 = float(v1)
        v2 = float(v2)
        r.set(v1 + v2)

    r = StringVar()
    r.set(0)
    Label(cp, textvariable = r).pack()
    calc_b = Button(cp, text = "Calcular", command = plus).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
    v1 = Entry(cp)
    v1.pack()
    v2 = Entry(cp)
    v2.pack()
```

I said that I already tested it on a file and it works, so I don't know where the error is, so I need your help. Thank you.

EDIT:
Now the error disappeared, but the label doesn't show the result. I think that I found the problem. When the code is in the function calc_price, the label doesn't show the result. When the code is in a new file the label works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You marked `v1`, `v2` and `r` as *globals*, but no such globals are defined.

The variables with the same names in `calc_price()` (not in the nested `plus`) are *not* globals. They are local names in that function. You'd have to mark them as global *at that scope level* too.

However, you'd then be *replacing* those variables with the result of the `.get()` calls; that is not something you want here.

*Remove* the `global` keywords, then use *different* filenames to store the `.get()` results:

```
def calc_price():
    cp = Tk()
    cp.title("Calcular Preço")

    def plus():
        v1result = v1.get()
        v2result = v2.get()
        v1result = float(v1result)
        v2result = float(v2result)
        r.set(v1result + v2result)

    r = StringVar()
    r.set(0)
    Label(cp, textvariable = r).pack()
    calc_b = Button(cp, text = "Calcular", command = plus).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
    v1 = Entry(cp)
    v1.pack()
    v2 = Entry(cp)
    v2.pack()
```

Now the code works as expected:

> [image: Tkinter calculator window]

By not assigning to `v1` and `v2` Python will look for their difinitions in the surrounding scope and find the variables in `calc_price`.

Comment: Thanks, the error disappeared. But the label doesn't show the result... Can you help?

Comment: @MatracadePlantão I see the label update; see the screenshot I included.

Comment: I think the problem is the `calc_price`. When the code is in the `calc_price` the label doesn't update.

Comment: @MatracadePlantão: All I did was add  `from Tkinter import *` in my interpreter, and called `calc_price()`; it works just fine then.